# Remove submit button styling

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to remove CSS styles from an submit button so that the default browser style is applied?

Comment: This is far too vague.  What styling rules are being applied now?  Input buttons should come out looking like the user's default rendering choice if no styles have been applied to it.

Comment: actually no. once you apply any styling to a button the default browser style no longer applies. I am asking how to reset it so that the default browser style is re-applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the styles to the system values,

```
input.overridecss {
    background-color: ButtonFace;
    color:ButtonText;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZDKQ/1/)

Here is a [list of values you can override](http://www.iangraham.org/books/xhtml1/appd/update-23feb2000.html), there is probably a better list but I'm lazy.

**[Edit]** Here is the [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#system-colors) which has been deprecated lol,

so here is the correct way I guess,

```
input[type=button] {
  appearance:push-button; /* expected from UA defaults */
}
```

from [Appearence](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#appearance)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
button {
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Hows that?

Answer (score 0):

Store styles that you're applying programatically in a CSS class. When you want to go back to default remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you dont mind to use jQuery, you can use following code to remove all styles and classes from submit buttons.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').removeClass();
$('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr("style");
```

This will remove all classes as well as inline styles, thus system default button style will be applied to your all submit buttons.

Comment: It won't remove any styling from a css file on only inputs though, ie.input[type="submit"] {color:red} will still be applied to the input after your calls.

Answer (score 0):

I found that because I had:

```
* { border: 0; padding: 0; }
```

etc etc.

in my code which affects submit buttons so I put this is instead:

```
*:not(input) { border: 0; padding: 0; } etc etc.
```

This seemed to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

If you're DEVELOPING the site - just remove the rules from the CSS file.

If you so wanted to, you could use Javascript/JQuery to remove/reset them based on some sort of condition if thats what you're looking for, ie:

```
$("#myButton").css("background","");
```

And so on...

If you're USING the site, but didn't build it - then you can (depending on your browser - i'm looking at Firefox 4) disable all or partial CSS from rendering using the web developer toolbar options... but I don't know if you can apply that as the 'default' setting for every site you load.

Comment: Why in gods name would you need to use jQuery for this?

Comment: I don't know, its not something i'd do personally - i'm just saying that its possible.  (And writing it as JQuery is just easier to demonstrate/read than vanilla JS).